# 2nd order nonhomogeneous differential equation solution missing an unknown term

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following equation:
$$ y'' - 3y' + 2y = e^x + 4x $$

I solved the homogeneous general solution, which is $$ Y_{CF} = Ae^x + Be^2x $$

For the particular solution, I tried this form $ Y_{PS} = Ce^x + Dx + E $, but since the term $ Ce^x $ already exist in $ Y_{CF} $, so I multiplied $ Y_{PS} $ with an $x$-term, and get $ Y_{PS} = Cxe^x + Dx^2 +Ex $

Its first derivative ${Y_{PS}}' = Ce^x(x+1) +2Dx +E $.

Second derivative $ {Y_{PS}}'' = Ce^x(x+2) + 2D$.

Plugging them back into the given equation, and solved for $C = -1, D = 0, E = 2$.

Which gives the particular solution $$ {Y_{PS}} = -xe^x + 2x $$

So my final answer is $$ y = Ae^x + Be^2x -xe^x + 2x $$

Or, alternatively factoring out the $ e^x $ from the first and third term $$ y = e^x(A-x) +Be^{2x} + 2x $$

However, the answer sheet is giving me an additional term, a constant $ + 3 $ at the end. Where did it come from, or did I missing something during my previous steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the issue is that you only multiply the terms that already exist in the homogeneous solution by $x$, so your particular solution should be
$$Y_{PS}=Cxe^x+Dx+E$$
$$Y_{PS}^{\prime}=C(x+1)e^x+D$$
$$Y_{PS}^{\prime\prime}=C(x+2)e^x$$
$$Y_{PS}^{\prime\prime}-3Y_{PS}^{\prime}+2Y_{PS}=-Ce^x+2Dx-3D+2E=e^x+4x$$
So $C=-1$, $D=2$, and $E=3$

Comment: Thank you! Gave it another go and got it right! Didn't grasp the concept 100%, now I got it.